# Fit QGraphisItem in view

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

Is a method to fit any image in view (that I import in QPixmap) and keep aspect ratio>. I try many solution but non of those works. 
Also I don't not sure what I need to fit? 
QGraphicsScene in QGraphicsView? Or QPixmap in QGraphicsView?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class GraphicsView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsView, self).__init__(parent)

        scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.setScene(scene)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = GraphicsView()
    photo = QtGui.QPixmap("image.jpg")
    w.scene().addPixmap(photo)
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the `fitInView()` method of QGraphicsView in the `resizeEvent()` method of QGraphicsView:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class GraphicsView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsView, self).__init__(parent)
        scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.setScene(scene)
        self.m_pixmap_item = self.scene().addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap())

    def setPixmap(self, pixmap):
        self.m_pixmap_item.setPixmap(pixmap)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        if not self.m_pixmap_item.pixmap().isNull():
            self.fitInView(self.m_pixmap_item, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        super(GraphicsView, self).resizeEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = GraphicsView()
    photo = QtGui.QPixmap("image.jpg")
    w.setPixmap(photo)
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It's work but I have a question, why dis you make a function "setPixmap" and above it you call: self.m_pixmap_item = self.scene().addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap())?

Comment: @Vesa95 Conceptually I understood that you only want to show an image so it is not necessary to export scene out of the class. So consider placing an item with an empty pixmap and the function will change only that pixmap. Do you know what the classes are for and their design? review some UML and concepts related to SW design.

Comment: now after your explanation I think I understood! Thank you a lot!